# Fence around electric meter

Tags: fence, meter, cover

I want to install a small fence/enclosure around my electric meter.

If there are no working clearances around meters I'd be in danger of violating, I'm thinking this fence only has to enclose a tight 12"x30" area. It should be about 6ft high though.

First question: are there electric codes I should worry about, like minimal working clearances?

Second question: because the fence will travel such a short distance, cementing posts seems like overkill (and it's also tricky to do that near the footer of the building). Do you think it'd be okay to just include some bracing in the fence/structure so that it's supported on the bottom and can stand up on its own without racking, then just anchor the whole thing to the studs of the building?

Lastly, this is just the first idea I had in mind. I am very open to other solutions. Have any of you prettied up your electric meters?

Comment: Who's your electric utility? Utility metering rules often strictly prohibit fencing off electric meters as you describe

Comment: I'm curious how you think a tiny fence pretties up a meter?

Comment: You are NOT ALLOWED to do that. They will cut your power.

Comment: To be honest, the meter itself isn't really an eyesore (I kind of like the meter box). What makes me cringe is the space below the meter where the vinyl siding has a ton of caulked-over screw holes from old cable/telephone wire boxes that used to be there. Replacing the siding around the sides and bottom of the meter seems tricky. The real solution is to train myself to not cringe hahaha

Comment: Fixing the siding sounds like a better way to approach this

Comment: please provide a picture of the meter and highlight where/what you'd like to improve

Answer (score 4):

[NEC 110.26](https://inspectapedia.com/electric/US-NEC-110.26-Electrical-Panel_Working-Space.pdf) specifies working space in front of electrical equipment that may need maintenance or servicing for 120v to ground be a minimum of 30" wide and 36" deep. Normally the meter itself is considered a component that may need servicing.

Your utility can impose additional requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Check with your utility company.

In our region the meter must be readable, which means in terms of an enclosure that the face must be visible. The face shows the serial number and the reading and the seal.

Furthermore the enclosure or its front must be easily removable so that the meter can be accessed from all sides for inspection, troubleshooting, maintenance, or replacement, by the utility company without further involvement by you. This access should be considered when fencing in, enclosing or surrounding with shrubs.

Such a box, and door-with-face-hole can be attached to the house and no feet are required.

Answer (score 0):

There are space requirements for working space around electrical panels, and no doubt also space requirements around meter boxes.

When you get electricity connected, they send a lineman in a truck out to hook you up.  if they feel unsafe working on live conductors around your meter box you don't get electric service that day.

Contact your electricity provider for guidance.  I would expect something like 3 feet of space being required in all directions (except into the wall)
eg: [that's what WE energies requires](https://www.we-energies.com/partners/builders/meter-installation-guidelines) also standing room.

If you must have this fence, make it portable so it can be moved when needed.  eg pour a 12"x30" concrete slab above ground and bolt your fence posts to that only. Now it's not a fence it's yard furniture!